# How to use wikipedia data downloaded from Hugging face in pyspark

Tags: nlp, huggingface-datasets

I am following - https://huggingface.co/datasets/wikipedia/blob/main/README.md , from hugging face to download dataset of wikipedia , for NLP

I ran the below command as per the hugging face to downlaod dataset

from datasets import load_dataset
load_dataset("wikipedia", "20220301.en")

These two files got downloaded ,  how do i use this file (wikipedia-train.arrow) to read the data in pyspark
total 19800320
-rw------- 1 root root 20275516160 May 19 20:43 wikipedia-train.arrow
-rw------- 1 root root        1135 May 19 20:43 dataset_info.json

[data set is like this from hugging face for wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doeNj.png)

I am trying to read this wikipedia-train.arrow as parquet, it is giving error

f = spark.read.parquet("dbfs:/databricks/wikipedia-train.arrow")

-rw------- 1 root root 20275516160 May 19 20:43 wikipedia-train.arrow
-rw------- 1 root root        1135 May 19 20:43 dataset_info.json

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.